# Specifying `path` for multi-variable responses with Chainlink

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to understand the documentation for making multi-variable requests with Chainlink ([docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/)), and something that is unclear is how to specify how the multiple values are queried. With the single-variable example ([docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/)), we see explicitly how the path is added. But for the multi-variable example, no paths are included, and nowhere is it indicated how the multiple values are denoted or returned.

Is there a more complete example showing how the various return values are specified in the request?

Here is the example for a single-variable:

```
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        request.addInt("times", 10**18);
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
```

And here is the example for multi-variable, which seems to leave out key details:

```
  function requestMultipleParameters(bytes32 specId, uint256 payment) public
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillMultipleParameters.selector);
    req.addUint("times", 10000);
    requestOracleData(req, payment);
  }
```

I guess I'm looking for way to specify multiple `path`s in the second example.

Comment: For the multi-variable example, all of the data is parsed inside the job spec instead of the smart contract: https://docs.chain.link/docs/example-job-spec-multi-word/

Comment: Right, so it's actually the same spec, but if you're using that specific job, you're using a job spec that won't work for what you're trying to do